# Do any substances in a liquid state work as well as water to put out fires?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there a liquid substance or compound that works as well to put out fire as water does?

Comment: I'd say many would do _better_ then water, for they evaporate easier and choke the flame with their vapors. We still use water because it is cheap and environment friendly.

Comment: Water is used because cities have giant tanks of it. Liquid nitrogen would be more effective but you don't have enough.

Answer (score 0):

Carbon tetrachloride was once used for this purpose as it has practically no flammability at lower temperatures .